# What is the correct MySQL syntax for a query with a COUNT from another table as a column?

Tags: mysql

Here is a query I've used that almost does what I want:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(p.prize_id) as number_prizes
FROM tbl_draw d 
  INNER JOIN tbl_prize p ON p.draw_id=d.draw_id 
WHERE d.draw_id={$draw_id}
```

The key point is that it counts the number of items from tbl_prize that matches on draw_id and presents that number as a new column 'number_prizes' in the result set.  For this query, the result set is a single row, because of the final WHERE clause that matches on a specific draw_id.

I want it to return ALL of the rows from tbl_draw with that same calculation per row. My problem is that when I remove the final clause "WHERE d.draw_id={$draw_id}", the result collapses all the rows into one, and is only sending back the first such row found in tbl_draw and with 'number_prizes' being a total of all

How can I phrase the query better?

[image]

Comment: Here's what's customary: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `group by` clause, naming all columns, eg:

```
<your query>
group by col1, col2, ... -- list all other columns
```

Comment: Okay, or even just "GROUP BY draw_id" is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you should use the group by after the end of your query, like this:

SELECT *, COUNT(p.prize_id) as number_prizes
FROM tbl_draw d
INNER JOIN tbl_prize p ON p.draw_id=d.draw_id
WHERE d.draw_id={$draw_id}
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, coln.....

And, if you want the id from tbl_draw, your SELECT must be like:

SELECT d.id as draw_id, *, COUNT(p.prize_id) as number_prizes

Comment: You can be 100 percent certain that a query certain that a query that begins `*` and ends `GROUP BY` is not going to go well.

Answer (score 0):

I **strongly** recommend that you do *not* use `SELECT *, ...` here.  *List* all of the columns that form the groups within the `SELECT` clause, then repeat that list within `GROUP BY`.

Here's why:  "`SELECT *` will work *only until someone adds a column to that table!"*  Which of course *will* happen someday.

Then, all of the sudden, your query will start failing, because `*` references this new column *(which presumably you don't care about anyway ...),* which is not in the `GROUP BY` list as is required.

Always *specify* exactly what columns (and aggregate functions ...) *your* query needs.  You'll be very glad you did.  (And so will your co-workers!)